# Proof of $\int f(x) \pm g(x)\,dx = \int f(x)\,dx \pm \int g(x)\, dx$.

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

I want to prove that $\int f(x) \pm g(x)\,dx = \int f(x)\,dx \pm \int g(x)\, dx$.

I am familiar with the proof for this fact for derivatives using differentiation from first principles, but I am not too sure how to prove this property of integrals.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it Riemann integral?

Comment: What is your definition of an integral? The answer depends  on it.

Comment: What tools are you starting with that you can use?

Comment: My knowledge of calculus is fairly limited (I know the techniques and applications of differentiation and am a little rusty with integration, but could remember the techniques of it if I needed). I am not familiar with analysis, which I have a feeling this question relies upon haha.

Comment: Well, this question relies heavily on what your definition of an integral is. Don't worry: Once you fix a definition, the proof is likely completely straight forward.

Comment: My definition of an integral is the process of finding the antiderivative, or in other words, finding a function A(x), given an expression for the first derivative of A(x).

Comment: Do you know what partitions are and how they are used to define the Riemann integral?

Comment: Not entirely. Are you talking about the intervals between the rectangles that you can break the area under a curve into (a Reimann sum I think its called)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $~F(x)~$ is an [anti-derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) of $~f(x)~$ and $~G(x)~$ is an anti-derivative of $~g(x)~$. So by the definition of anti-derivative $~F'\left( x \right) = f\left( x \right)~$ and $~G'\left( x \right) = g\left( x \right)~$.

Also by the basic properties of derivatives $$~{\left( {F\left( x \right) \pm G\left( x \right)} \right)^\prime } = \,F'\left( x \right) \pm G'\left( x \right) = f\left( x \right) \pm g\left( x \right)~.$$

So $~\,F\left( x \right) + G\left( x \right)~$ is an anti-derivative of  $~\,f\left( x \right) + g\left( x \right)~$ and $~\,F\left( x \right) - G\left( x \right)~$ is an anti-derivative of  $~\,f\left( x \right) - g\left( x \right)~$.

Hence $$~\int\left[{{f\left( x \right) \pm g\left( x \right)}}\right] \,dx= F\left( x \right) \pm G\left( x \right) + c = \left(\int{{f\left( x \right)\,dx}}\right) \pm \left(\int{{g\left( x \right)\,dx}}\right)~.$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $F$ is a primitive function of $f$ and $G$ primitive function of $g$, then:
$$(F(x) + G(x))' = F'(x) + G'(x) =f(x) + g(x)$$
from this follows that $F + G$ is a primitive function of $f + g$.